# how to move a image by touching and place in another location   in iphone 

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm developing a "match the correct pair" answer app.

Here there will be  two sections.(for example animal and legs).

In animal section there will hen,dog,cow,fox etc.(These options will be static.)

Now under the legs section there will be 2,4,5,6 etc.

The 2,4,5,6 etc will be random order.

The user will suppose select "2" and move to "hen" then the match is correct and will award a point.

If user select "2" and moved to "dog" the match is wrong and no point is awarded.

So how can i implement the moving function and also to check  the correct match.

I hope i have explained my doubt in detail and if not please forgive me and im ready to explain more if needed.

Can anyone please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you need to drag it? Or just move?

Answer (score 2):

Since it would be static, you will have the frame positions of each label (leg) I guess. You can find which label has been selected by using `CGRectContainsPoint` in `touchesBegan: withEvent:` method.

You can move the label by setting its frame position continuously in `touchesMoved: withEvent:` method.

Again you have to find whether this label intersects any label in animal side.

**Edit:**
For moving a view, pl. refer Listing 2-4 in [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html)

Comment: ,im for the very first time implementing this.Can you please suggest any tutorial or sample code for this.

Comment: ,thanks for your help.can u tell me the code for detecting the correct match please.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't need to drag it, just set some buttons for your legs section, and set title (or any image) for them useing your random variables. In callbacks for this buttons "remember" what of them was pressed (optional, set other buttons userIntractionAnabled property to "NO"). then, make more buttons for your animal section. when user pressed one of tham, just move your legs-buttons to any position:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        [button setCenter:CGPointMake(X, Y)];
    }];
```

just in case:
in your buttons callback you have a "sender" value. this is pressed button. so you can use it:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
            [sender setCenter:CGPointMake(X, Y)];
        }];
```

Comment: ,can u please tell me in little more detail how to detect the correct match,i.e dog - 4.

Comment: you can set tag to all leg-buttons and animal buttons ([button setTag:(any number)];) and look at tags of pressed buttons

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

touchDone=YES;

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

[self loadingView];

}

-(void) loadingView{

if (touchDone){
        drawImage.frame = CGRectMake(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y, 70, 70);

}

}
```

Comment: After touching the view you can get the point coordinates and then reset the frame of the image. I have done this for one UIImageView. Do it generally for all the images and after that check the condition if the correct pair have same y coordinate with +/- 10 point error if you want to align vertically.

Comment: @coolanikothari,thanku so much.But what i want is to drag the image and place it in a different position.Can you pleas tell me how to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

.h viewController

```
@interface TouchViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIView *viewImage;
    IBOutlet UILabel *touchesLabel;
    CGPoint lastPoint;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView  *viewImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *touchesLabel;

-(void) redrawView:(CGPoint) lpoint;

@end
```

in .m Implementation file

```
@implementation TouchViewController

@synthesize   touchesLabel,viewImage;

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    [self redrawView:lastPoint];
}


- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];  
    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    [self redrawView:lastPoint];
}

-(void) redrawView:(CGPoint) lpoint
{
    viewImage.frame=CGRectMake(lpoint.x, lpoint.y, 40, 30);
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [viewImage release];
    [touchesLabel release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

*Note ViewImage is UIView Type but contains the image...can you how to upload on stackoverflow so that i will upload my project here if you want.